# Strange behavior for list and overflow: hidden

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

Problem:
If used overflow:hidden on element inside list (inside "li" tag) some strange things happens.

HTML:

```
<ul class="test">
    <li><a href="#">some text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">some text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">some text</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style-position: outside;
}

a {
    display: block;
}

ul.test a {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Valid result:

[image: valid result]

Result in IE 8-11:

[image: IE 8-11 result]

Some gap behind links.

Result in Chrome:

[image: chrome result]

List markers disappear.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/er1hsabb/2/

Question: What wrong? How prevent this?

Comment: It looks fine on IE8 for me, but the markers are not displayed on Chrome37

Comment: I've realized that it happens because of `a { display: block; }` declaration. It seems Chrome gets confused and hides the markers as they are outside of the computed width area. Using `list-style-position: inside;` may fix that.

Comment: use `a {display: inline-block;}` - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/er1hsabb/5/)

Comment: I tested with developer tools in IE 11. Now I open in IE 8.0.6001.18702 - same problem. JsFiddle don't work properly in IE 8 - i use direct link for result: http://jsfiddle.net/er1hsabb/2/show/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found next solution:

1. Hide marker
2. Create own marker use :before

Added CSS:

```
ul.test {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}

ul.test li {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 40px;
}

ul.test li:before {
    content: "●";
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px; 
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/er1hsabb/6/

All worked in Opera, FF, Chrome and IE 8+.

"Marker" size is bigger from default, but it may changed from CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/er1hsabb/7/

Answer (score 0):

Changing this:

```
ul.test a {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

to this:

```
ul.test li {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

solves the spacing problem on IE and looks similar to that of Chrome. working [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/er1hsabb/3/)

and adding `list-style-position: inside;` solves the `list-style` for Chrome. refer to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/er1hsabb/4/)

Comment: In FF markers gone in both links. In Chrome too. And IE 11 - same. About "inside" - I know this. But this have other problems: marker treated as float elements.